# How to show React pages in Spring Boot?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I created a Spring backend with a React front end and used the maven-frontend-plugin to combine both into a single project which I can build into a .jar file.

The problem I encountered is that now React isn't taking precedence over Spring Boot, if that makes sense.

For example, these are the routes I've defined in React using react-router(v6)

```
    <div className="App">
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<MainScreen />} />
                    <Route path="/item/:productId" element={<NewItem />} />
                    <Route path="/categories/:categoryId" element={<Items />} />
                    <Route path="/items/search/" element={<Items />} />
                    <Route path="/items/search/:searchTerm" element={<Items />} />
                    <Route path="/registration" element={<NewRegistrationScreen />} />
                    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen />} />
                    <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
                    <Route path="/account" element={<Account />} />
                    <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundScreen />} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
```

And in each of those routes I consume the API served by the backend. But now when I navigate to the url designated in these routes, I get a Whitelabel Error Page indicating that React isn't the one handling that route/url but Spring Boot is.

When I use the Link component from the react-browser-dom it works "normally" as long as the page isn't refreshed. If it is, the same Whitelabel error is shown.

```
<Link to="/login">To Login</Link>
<Link to="/cart">To Cart</Link>
<Link to="/account">To Account</Link>
```

Is there any way to fix this problem? Apologies if this isn't properly articulated or explained, this is my first time doing a project like this and the problem is very new to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add a controller which redirects the requests so React can handle them.

```
@Controller
public class RouteController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^.]*}")
        public String redirectSingle() {
            return "forward:/";
    }

   @GetMapping("/*/{path:[^.]*}")
        public String redirectNested() {
            return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the need of get mapping in this scenario?

Comment: I have the same question as @SaurabhGupta , but again I created a controller like this and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `BrowserRouter` tag and also this route format:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/item">
            <Route path=":itemId" element={<NewItem/>} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/item">
            <Route path=":itemId" element={<Item/>} />
        </Route>
    <Routes>
<BowserRouter />
```